# Active transactions and PHP

Tags: php, yii, transactions

Given a PHP class with several functions of the style

```
public function $op_Data() {
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("");
    $transaction = Yii::app->db->beginTransaction();

    try {
      //code here
      $transaction->commit()
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $transaction->rollback();
      return "Operation Failed\n" . $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

is it possible to continue usage of the transaction from previous methods after a commit operation is successful or error is returned?

what I mean is, an insert function is called.  It checks if a transaction is active, and uses it.  If a transaction is not active, it creates one.  The same check occurs for all functions that require transaction functionality.

If this functionality exists, does it affect the commit/rollback operations within the particular function?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to execute SQL queries placed in separate methods in a single transaction you can wrap them like this:

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    $instance->insertMethod();
    $instance->updateMethod();
    $instance->deleteMethod();
    // ...more DB methods calls
    $transaction->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

In this case, however, you have to check in your methods whether transaction has been already created outside. It could be done using `CDbConnection`'s [getCurrentTransaction(](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#getCurrentTransaction-detail)) method someway like this:

```
public function $op_Data() {
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("");
    $transaction = Yii::app()->db->getCurrentTransaction();
    if ($transaction !== null) {
        // Transaction already started outside
        $transaction = null;
    }
    else {
        // There is no outer transaction, creating a local one
        $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    }

    try {
      //code here
      if ($transaction !== null)
          $transaction->commit()
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      if ($transaction !== null)
          $transaction->rollback();
      return "Operation Failed\n" . $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If preserving the code of existing PHP class is the preferrable way to go you can also look at opportunity to override default implementation of PHP's `PDO` class. [This nested transactions implementation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/38/how-to-use-nested-db-transactions-mysql-5-postgresql/) is a skeleton for possible solution. The main idea is to start the only transaction on first call of `beginTransaction()` and really end the transaction on Nth call of `commit()` or `rollback()`, where N - is a count of sequental `beginTransaction()` calls.

Comment: If the transaction had previously been committed or rolled back, calling subsequent commit/rollback will be futile (no begin).

Comment: You are right about this but the workaround proposed above will never make subsequent `commit()` or `rollback()` calls. When `commit()` or `rollback()` is called on `CDbTranscation` instance its `_active` state is turned to `false` and `getCurrentTransaction()` returns `null` then. That's why modified method of PHP class will start and commit/rollback its own local transaction only when no any other transaction has been started. In other case the method doesn't handle any transaction itself allowing to do it outside.

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Your first solution was what I basically implemented as a test after asking the question.  My concern with reusing existing active transactions was in regard to commit/rollback integrity.  After testing, I've confirmed that there were no issues with several incorrect commits rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on your database engine, but usually once a transaction has been rolled back or committed, you will have to "create" a new one.

A transaction is a "savepoint" within your database engine and should have no impact on your php code.